# LongItemClickListener on Listview android

Tags: android, listview, view, onitemclicklistener

I have a question, Can we apply `OnItemClickLisyener` and `OnLongItemClickListener` on the same ListView?
I want to delete items of listview on long item click, listview is already handling `ItemClickListener`  to view files.

What should I do now?

Can someOne explain how to do this?

Comment: yes you can apply onItemClickListener and onItemLongClickListener both.

Comment: Agree with @Ravi Go ahead.... :)

Comment: but how? can u explain it to me ? by using any example plz

Comment: @SparrOw yes you can do it easily.

Comment: pratik check Ravi's answer .. will it work in my project?

Comment: @SparrOw ya it will work, if it will not work then there must be a reason that, you can not put 2 click events on one element.

Comment: but pratik i want to view file on itemclick and delete the same file onLongItemClick.. now what should i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54839/discussion-between-pratik-and-sparrow).

Comment: @SparrOw join conversation jiya..

Comment: i am in software house right now pratik .. cant chat at dis time :)

Comment: i will talk to you about dis later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                        //do your stuff
            });                
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
//Do your stuff                               
}});
```

Comment: i want to view file on itemclick and delete the same file onLongItemClick. @Ravi

Comment: for View file open file by getting file object and on ItemLonkClick you have to delete file and remove item from adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ,Hope It Will work